# SVD with non invertible matrices

Tags: matrices, svd

My problem:

> Assuming A is a $n \times n$ matrix and can be expressed as $A=U\Sigma V^T = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$ and it is not invertible.
>
> Given $B=\sum_{i=1}^r \frac{1}{\sigma_i} v_i u_i^T$, show that $BAx = x$ for all $x = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_iv_i$.

What I have done so far:

1. I rewrote $B$ as $B = V\Sigma^+U^T$ where $\Sigma^+$ is a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with: $\sigma^+_i =
       \begin{cases}
           \sigma^{-1}_i & \textit{if } i \leq r \\
           0 & \textit{otherwise}
       \end{cases}$
2. I rewrote $x$ as $x = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i v_i = \bar{\alpha} V$ where $\bar{\alpha} =
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \alpha_1, & \alpha_2, & \dots, & \alpha_r, & 0, & \dots, & 0      
   \end{pmatrix}^T = 
   \begin{pmatrix} 
       \underset{(rx1)}{\bar{\alpha}}\\
       0
   \end{pmatrix} \in \mathcal{R}^n$

**Question 1:**

> I used
> $\underset{n \times n}{V} = \begin{pmatrix} 
>     \underset{(r\times r)}{V} & 0\\
>     0 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$,
> $\underset{n \times n}{\Sigma} = \begin{pmatrix} 
>     \underset{(r\times r)}{\Sigma} & 0\\
>     0 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$,
> $\underset{n \times n}{\Sigma^+} = \begin{pmatrix} 
>     \underset{(r\times r)}{\Sigma^+} & 0\\
>     0 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$ because I assumed that besides the index $r$, the other values of $\Sigma$ would be all $0$ (in the definition the summatory was until $r$ and $r \leq n$).
>
> Is it correct? If not why?

3. I substituted the new terms in the expression:

$BAx = x \rightarrow (V\Sigma^+ U^T) (U \Sigma V^T) x = x \rightarrow (V \Sigma^+) (\Sigma V^T) \bar{\alpha} V = \bar{\alpha} V \rightarrow$

$\rightarrow V \underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \underset{(r\times r)}{\Sigma^{-1}} & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \underset{(r\times r)}{\Sigma} & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathcal{I}_{r\times r}}
V^T \bar{\alpha} V = \bar{\alpha} V \rightarrow$

$\rightarrow
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \underset{(r\times r)}{V} & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \underset{(r\times r)}{\mathcal{I}} & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \underset{(r\times r)}{V^T} & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathcal{I}_{r\times r}} \bar{\alpha} V = \bar{\alpha} V \rightarrow \bar{\alpha} V = \bar{\alpha} V$

**Question 2**

> Is it correct? If not, why? How can I prove the assignment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1: you should write $x = V \bar \alpha$ rather than $x = \bar \alpha V$; note that $x$ must be a column vector. Also, we have no reason to assume that $U$ and $V$ have zero-rows and zero-columns.

Regarding the problem itself, here is a much simpler proof. If $x = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i v_i$, then we can write
$$
\begin{align}
Ax & = 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i u_iv_i^T \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^r \alpha_j v_j \right)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r \alpha_j\sigma_i \cdot u_i(v_i^Tv_j)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^r  \alpha_i\sigma_i \cdot u_i,
\end{align}
$$
and similarly
$$
\begin{align}
BAx & = B(Ax) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^r \frac 1{\sigma_i} v_iu_i^T \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^r \alpha_j \sigma_j u_j \right)
\\ & = 
\sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r \frac{\alpha_j \sigma_j}{\sigma_i} v_i(u_i^Tu_j)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^r  \frac{\alpha_i \sigma_i}{\sigma_i} v_i = x,
\end{align}
$$
which was what we wanted.

---

If you prefer to work with matrices, you could also have used $x = V \bar \alpha$ and $B = V \Sigma^+ U^T$ to find that
$$
\begin{align}
BAx & = (V \Sigma^+ U^T)(U\Sigma V^T)(V\bar \alpha)
\\ & = V \Sigma^+ (U^TU)\Sigma (V^TV)\bar \alpha
\\ & = V (\Sigma^+ \Sigma) \bar \alpha
\\ & = V \bar \alpha = x.
\end{align}
$$
However, the fact that $U^TU, V^TV$ are identity matrices and that $(\Sigma^+ \Sigma) \bar \alpha = \bar \alpha$ should be justified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that we cannot assume U and V to have zero colums/rows. But why should I justify that $U^TU$,$V^TV$ are identity matrices? Doesn't it come from the SVD technique? Also, $Σ^+Σ$ is not an identity matrix because some values on the diagonal will be zero; does it affect the calculation?

Comment: I would say that it comes from “the definition of SVD” rather than “the SVD technique”. Note that there are different versions of the SVD, you could have the “full, skinny, or reduced” SVDs. To your second point, in the reduced SVD we have $\Sigma^+\Sigma =I$, but the key point in general is to argue that $\Sigma^+ \Sigma\bar \alpha=\bar \alpha$ since only the leading $r$ entries of $\alpha$ are non-zero